# How to interpret Hamiltonian in terms of its matrix representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, hamiltonian-formalism, quantum-chemistry

I am reading a research paper (*A Theoretical Analysis of Zero Field Splitting Parameters of Mn2+ Doped Diglycine Calcium Chloride Tetrahydrate*) where they state the Hamiltonian term:
$$H=\frac{F}{180}\left\{35 S_{z}^{4}-30 S(S+1) S_{z}^{2}+25 S_{z}^{2}-6 S(S+1)+3 S^{2}(S+1)^{2}\right\}$$
I want to write this as a matrix, but I am unsure how to interpret the different terms. As far as I understand, $S_z$ is the spin-operator, i.e. a matrix, and $S_z^4=\hat{S}_z\hat{S}_z\hat{S}_z\hat{S}_z$. For the rest of the terms, I believe $S$ is simply the spin quantum number, i.e. a scalar so that for a quintet state the term reads:
$$\hat{H}=\frac{F}{180}\left\{35 \hat{S}_{z}^{4}-30\cdot2(2+1) \hat{S}_{z}^{2}+25 \hat{S}_{z}^{2}-6\cdot 2(2+1)\mathbb{I}+3\cdot2^{2}(2+1)^{2}\mathbb{I}\right\}$$
Where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix. Can someone confirm if this is correct?

Comment: Would you please add the link to the research paper you mentioned?

Comment: Looks right, alright.

Comment: The PDF can be found here: https://www.ps-taiwan.org/cjp/download.php?type=paper&vol=52&num=1-I&page=262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $S$ is not a scalar, it is an operator! If $\{\chi_{s,m_s}\}$ is the simultaneous eigenbasis of $S_{z}$ and $S(S+1)$, then

$$\tag{2} S(S+1) \chi_{s,m_s}= s(s+1) \hbar^{2} \chi_{s,m_s} $$

$$\tag{1} S_{z} \chi_{s,m_s} =  m_{s}\hbar \chi_{s,m_s}$$

However, as $[S(S+1),S_{z}]=0$ and the quantum number $s$ is the same throughout this problem, the operator $S(S+1)$ can be replaced by $s(s+1) \hbar^{2} \mathbb{I}$. Therefore, the given Hamiltonian can be written as

$$\tag{3}\hat{H}=\frac{F}{180}\left\{35 \hat{S}_{z}^{4}-30\cdot 2(2+1) \hbar^{2} \hat{S}_{z}^{2}+25 \hat{S}_{z}^{2}-6\cdot 2(2+1)\hbar^{2}\mathbb{I}+3\cdot2^{2}(2+1)^{2}\hbar^{4}\mathbb{I}\right\}$$

If we work in units of $\hbar$(see [Planck's unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#:%7E:text=The%20five%20universal%20constants%20that%20Planck%20units%2C%20by,%2F%204%20%CF%80%CE%B50%205%20the%20Boltzmann%20constant%2C%20kB)), the operator $S(S+1)$ can be replaced by $s(s+1) \mathbb{I}$ and
the second expression for the Hamiltonian that you have written holds true.

**Note :** In a lot of texts, the operator $S(S+1)$ is written as $S^{2}$ so that

$$\tag{4} S^{2} \chi_{s,m_s}= s(s+1) \hbar^{2} \chi_{s,m_s} $$

Comment: @JKalle let me know if you want the explicit expressions for the $S_z$ and $S(S+1)$ matrices.

Comment: Is there a reason $S^2$ is sometimes written $S(S+1)$? That seems like bizarre notation.

Comment: @Charlie It is true that the notation is unusual. I think the notation is useful in the sense that the operator $S$ can be substituted with the quantum number $s$ to get the eigenvalue when working in units of $\hbar$. I recently encountered this notation in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_field_splitting). Instead of  the usual $S_{x}^{2}+S_{y}^{2}+S_{z}^{2}=S^{2}$,  it used $S_{x}^{2}+S_{y}^{2}+S_{z}^{2}=S(S+1)$

Comment: I asked a similar question a few days ago and was told that $S(S+1)$ should be interpreted as the operator $S(S+1)=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
S(S+1) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & S(S+1) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & S(S+1)
\end{array}\right]$ for a triplet state. This implies that $S$ is a scalar, but he must have referred to the replacement to $s(s+1) \mathbb{I}$ as you say. 
The explicit matrix for $S_z$ should be the standard spin-z operator and $S(S+1)$ a matrix  with $s(s+1)$ along the diagonal, unless there is something I have gotten terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct. All you have to do is write the powers of $S_z$ in matrix form, and add a unit matrix factor for the terms without $S_z$.